# Architectural reasons behind the Twilio C# 5.x library

Tags: c#, twilio

I upgraded the latest nuget package for the Twilio C# and noticed that most of the usage is based on static methods and no async calls.

Is there a reason for not using async/await and instance methods?

Comment: Async is supported by the library. Instead of MessageResource.Create, for example, call MessageResource.CreateAsync

Answer (score 1):

Twilio Developer Educator here. This is the kind of valuable feedback we really want to hear from the developer community, even if it's hard for us to hear. Let me address the two parts of your question:

*1. Regarding lack of async/await support.*

The library does in fact support this, assuming you are targeting .NET 4.5.1 or later. For these platforms, we use `HttpClient` under the hood which supports true async. Instead of calling, for example, `MessageResource.Create`, you would instead call `MessageResource.CreateAsync`. Here's a note from the docs on this: https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/csharp/migrating-your-csharp-dot-net-application-twilio-sdk-4x-5x#asynchronous-methods

*2. Regarding the static nature of the resources.*

Here was the thinking behind it... We wanted to spare developers from needing to pass a client object throughout their application. Not everyone uses a dependency injection framework, and we wanted to remove as much friction as possible. For those that do, they will do well to inject their own client object.

We acknowledge this makes the unit testing story less than ideal and will be working to make this easier. We'll start by working on a blog post that outlines how to mock your own client and return various responses. We'll continue on that by updating the library and adding tools to make doing this as easy as possible.

**UPDATE:**
I put together an example on how you can mock a Twilio API request. We'll be releasing an update to make this even easier.
https://github.com/dprothero/twilio-mock-example

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for not using `async` methods in a library is because the library is not making *true* `async` calls. By *true* I mean I/O operations and not some CPU bound code wrapped in a `Task.Run()`. You can imagine if you have a web app and a third party lib starts up heaps of `Task.Run()` operations under the guise that the method is `async`, that will not be good for your app's performance and throughput.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. You can execute code asynchronously that doesn't require "CPU bound code" wrapped with the async. Like for example, making a request to a REST API (like HttpClient does perfectly fine).

Comment: HttpClient makes a _true_ `async` call. That is NOT CPU bound code.

Comment: @JLuisEstrada `HttpClient` does not use `Task.Run()` in its `async` implementations.

Comment: Async is supported by the Twilio library. Instead of MessageResource.Create, for example, call MessageResource.CreateAsync